# I want to replace Toggle Button by icons

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I want to replace Toggle Button by Icon. It means when Toggle Button is True I want to Show Icons.light_mode and if it is false I want to show icons.dark_mode in Flutter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check this code below

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool isDarkMode = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: [
            Switch(value: isDarkMode, onChanged: (val) {
              setState(() {
                isDarkMode = !isDarkMode;
              });
            })
          ],
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Icon(isDarkMode ? Icons.dark_mode : Icons.light_mode),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Pleased to help you also marked this as answer if it helped you.